# Regular languages closed under prefix operation

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata, closure-properties

Suppose that $D$ is a regular language over an alphabet $A$. How can I prove that the following language is also regular?
$$ \mathrm{LANGUAGE}_2(D) := \{ d \mid d,t \in A^* \text{ and } dt \in D \} $$
(This problem is taken from *Introduction to the Theory of Computation* by Mike Sipser.)

Comment: This is a very standard exercise. It was asked on [math.se]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656668/proving-that-reguarity-is-closed-under-prefixes, and probably elsewhere.

Comment: Had no idea, thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

(1) If the regular language is given by a *finite state automaton* $M$ the language of prefixes can be obtaines by extending the set of accepting states. Choose all states that lie on a path from initial state to one of the original accepting states.

The prefix operation is a special case of the operation quotient

$K/L = \{ x \mid xy\in L, \text{ for some } y\in K\}$

where we take $L$ to be the language $A^*$ of all strings. Surprisingly, the regular languages are closed under quotient by *arbitrary* languages.
See [are regular languages closed under division](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/34008/4287), and [Closure against right quotient with a fixed language](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/1554/4287).

(2) If the regular language is given by a *regular expression* instead, then we can construct a new regular expression for the prefix language, directly using the inductive definition of regular expressions. See [Regularity of “middles” of words from regular language](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/27556/4287).

(3) Also, there is a characterization in terms of *Myhill-Nerode equivalence classes*: a language is regular iff its number of equivalence classes is finite. In can be observed that $x \equiv_L y$ implies $x\equiv_{\text{pref }L} y$, so if $\equiv$ is of finite index, then so is $\equiv_{\text{pref }L}$.
More on this see [Myhill-Nerode and closure properties](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/7441/4287).

(As Yuval noted, the exercise is somewhat standard, but I would like to have some remarks here to close the issue. Feel free to add relevant links.)